# If statement not effective

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, ncurses

```
void spriteput(int x,int y, int stype)
{
    char sprite1[5]="OOOO";
    char sprite2[5]="OOOO";
    char sprite3[5]="OOOO";
    char sprite4[5]="OOOO";
    if (stype == 1)
    {
        char sprite1[5] = " OO ";
        char sprite2[5] = "OOOO";
        char sprite3[5] = "OOOO";
        char sprite4[5] = " OO ";
        mvprintw(2,y,"%s \n",sprite1);
    }
    mvprintw(x+1,y,"%s \n",sprite2);
    mvprintw(x+2,y,"%s \n",sprite3);
    mvprintw(x+3,y,"%s \n",sprite4);
}
```

If I'm correct that block of code should print out on a NCURSES screen

```
 OO  
OOOO
OOOO
 OO
```

Instead however, it prints out the default text (the first char statements). Can anyone tell me why this is? The `printw` statement inside the If-block prints out the proper text, so it's being assigned correctly. Thank you in advance.

Comment: All right, I have realized I'm an idiot in this situation >_<. No need for more answers.

Comment: No self-flagellation necessary.  8v)  Go ahead and accept your favorite answer, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your declarations inside the `if` statement are shadowing the declarations outside it; once the if-statement exits, those shadowed declarations are out of scope and gone forever.

To work around this, you could do something like

```
if (stype == 1)
{
    sprite1[0] = ' ';
    sprite1[3] = ' ';
    // ...
```

Or you could use a function like `strcpy` to accomplish the same thing.

This is a situation where compiling with full warnings turned on would have shown you the error without needing to post here, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring them as local variables in the 'if' block.  They don't affect the strings in function scope.

Answer (score 1):

You are making another set of local variables with the same name (sprite1, sprite2, etc) in the block local to the `if (stype == 1)` which shadows the declarations at the outer level.  Use this instead:

```
if (stype == 1)
{
    sprintf(sprite1, "%s", " OO ");
    // etc
}
```

Comment: why use `sprintf()` where `strcpy()` is sufficient?